# Boot stick not detected

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, startup

My company provided me with a secure boot stick from ECOS which shall boot Linux on any Mac or PC when plugged-in. However, my MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2019, Two Thunderbolt 3 ports, BigSur Version 11.2.3) does not detect the bootable device when I press `option` after having started. According to Disk Utility, it is a FAT16 system which prints me an error if I press `mount` in disk utility. Does anyone know a workaround?

As I need to use this stick for working from home, I really appreciate any kind of help!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I see two potential issues - 1. what format is the stick? 2. Is secure boot on?

Comment: According to disk utility, it is a FAT16 system which prints me an error when I press "mount" in disk utility (I can provide pictures if needed). I have already disabled secure boot!

Comment: FAT16 ought to mount, but I'd be very surprised if it would boot. I'll have to leave the details to someone more au fait with newer MacBooks, but thank you for the additional info. Could you edit that into your original question for completeness?

Comment: Their site reckons it ought to boot, but they seem to have several versions of the stick, none of which I have any experience with. https://www.ecos.de/en/products-1/secure-boot-stick/secure-boot-stick-sx?L=1

Comment: I have seen this stick working on an old Windows notebook, so, in general, it should work...

Comment: There is no "in general" getting a Mac vs PC to boot. They require very different things.

Comment: It seems like the problem stems from Apple's T2 chip, though I've disabled secure booting. The stick can be booted from a 2016 MacBook Pro.

Comment: I think you're probably going to need to speak to IT/ECOS about it. As it's a secure device I'm fairly sure the structure isn't going to be published anywhere.